# showing rows if sub queries join columns if they exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to only return a row if either of the subquery returns a field.

```
SELECT upd8r_user_accts.id, (

SELECT fb_id
FROM upd8r_facebook_accts
WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id
) as facebook, (

SELECT twitter
FROM upd8r_twitter_accts
WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id
) as twitter
FROM  `upd8r_user_accts`
```

also i am returning id/access token values for each of the subqueries- how could i return a boolean value of yes or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  upd8r_user_accts.id,
  upd8r_facebook_accts.fb_id  IS NOT NULL  AS has_fb_id,
  upd8r_twitter_accts.twitter IS NOT NULL  AS has_twitter
FROM
  upd8r_user_accts
LEFT JOIN
  upd8r_twitter_accts
    ON upd8r_twitter_accts.user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id
LEFT JOIN
  upd8r_facebook_accts
    ON upd8r_facebook_accts.user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id
WHERE
     upd8r_facebook_accts.fb_id  IS NOT NULL
  OR upd8r_twitter_accts.twitter IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT u.id, f.fb_id as facebook, t.twitter as twitter
FROM  upd8r_user_accts u
LEFT JOIN upd8r_facebook_accts f on f.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN upd8r_twitter_accts t on t.user_id = u.id
```

---

Now, if you want a yes or no in facebook and twitter, do it like this:

```
SELECT u.id,
       case when f.fb_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as facebook,
       case when t.twitter is null then 'no' else 'yes' as twitter
FROM  upd8r_user_accts u
LEFT JOIN upd8r_facebook_accts f on f.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN upd8r_twitter_accts t on t.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Your first query returns a row in any case, but the question was to return a row if either of subquery returns a row.

Comment: @Tim, but then he asked for returning yes/no, the first is a jump to my final proposal that is the second query.

Comment: @aF. - I think Tim means that the requirement `I want to only return a row if either of the subquery returns a field.` was missed out in these two answers.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to do is to check if there is a row in the corresponding table:

```
    SELECT upd8r_user_accts.id
           ,(SELECT fb_id
             FROM upd8r_facebook_accts
             WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id) as facebook
           ,(SELECT twitter
             FROM upd8r_twitter_accts
             WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id) as twitter
    FROM  upd8r_user_accts
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT fb_id
                  FROM upd8r_facebook_accts
                  WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id) 
          OR
          EXISTS (SELECT twitter
                  FROM upd8r_twitter_accts
                  WHERE user_id = upd8r_user_accts.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to left joining, try an inner join to a unioned set:

```
select u.id, 
       coalesce(max(a.fb_id), 'no') fb_id, 
       coalesce(max(a.twitter), 'no') twitter
from
(select id, 'yes' fb_id, null twitter from upd8r_facebook_accts
 union all
 select id, null fb_id, 'yes' twitter from upd8r_twitter_accts) a
join upd8r_user_accts u on a.id = u.user_id
group by a.id
```